# Angular Momentum with rotational kinematics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

You (with a mass of 75 kg) are standing at the edge of a stationary merry-go-round that has a mass of 900 kg and a radius of 4 m. You can assume that the merry-go-round is well approximated as a circular disc, with I = (1/2)MR^2. To get the merry-go-round spinning, you throw a 2 kg rock in the horizontal direction that is tangent to the outer edge of the merry-go-round at a speed of 8 m/s. What is the angular speed of the merry-go-round after the rock is thrown? You can treat the person as a point mass (I = MR^2)

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use conservation of angular momentum.

Big hint: you can treat the rock and the person as point masses. The angular momentum for a point mass is simply $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ where $\vec{p}$ is the linear momentum. Since the direction of $\vec{L}$ is along the axis of rotation, you can just use the magnitude of $\vec{L}$ in your conservation of momentum equation. Furthermore, the the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$ is $90^{\circ}$, the equation for the magnitude of the angular momentum becomes $L=rp=rmv$. Also recall the relationship that *in this case* $v=r\omega$.

To set up the problem, at the start, the angular momentum is $0$, since nothing is rotating. After that, the merry go round rotates with angular velocity $\omega$, and the person with linear velocity $r\omega$, and the rock with $v = 11\text{ m/s}$. Keep in mind that **the rock travels in the opposite direction as the person+merry go round.**

You should see a solution from here.